# Разбиение строки без пробелов на несколько слов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток, например, дана строка `ЯблокоАпельсинГруша` соответственно ее нужно разбить на три отдельных слова. Строка не статичная и слова в ней постоянно меняются. Как это лучше сделать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: и каждое новое слово начинается с большой буквы?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var str = "ЯблокоАпельсинГруша";
str = str.replace(/([А-Я])/g, ' $1').split(' ');
var shift = str.shift();
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
   var li = document.createElement('li');
   li.innerHTML = str[i];
   list.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let source = 'ЯблокоАпельсинГрушаWatermelon';
console.log(source.split(/(?=[А-ЯA-Z])/));
```